# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. Can't find @followed.name but @followed is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, methods, undefined

I'm trying to show a user, another user's information. (The users are 'friends')

I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError in Users#show_follow
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

because of this bit of code:
    <%= @followed.name %>

I can't work out why the code can't find **@followed** as it's been assigned in the controller as I have done throughout the app. **@active_relationship** seems to be being assigned as it should. binding.pry wont open here either, again not sure why. Any ideas why I can't get **@followed.name** to show the name of the user being followed?

**show_follow.html.erb:**

```
<%= @active_relationship %>
<%= @followed.name %>
```

**user_controller:**

```
  def showf
    if params[:active_relationship]
      @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find_by(params[:active_relationship])
      @followed = @active_relationship.followed
    else 
      "No relationship found"
    end
  end
```

**user/model:**

```
has_many :active_relationships,   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id",
has_many :following,           -> { where(relationships: { state: "accepted" } ) },   through: :active_relationships,   source: :followed
```

**relationship/model:**

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
```

EDIT:
implemented the answer code from @choco and got binding.pry to work in the view. Outputs:

**params:**
=> {"active_relationship"=>"28", "action"=>"show_follow", "controller"=>"users"}

**current_user:**
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #

**@followed:**
=> nil

**@active_relationship:**
=> nil

**Why is @active_relationship nill when it's been set from the params that are proven to be there??**

Comment: "but @followed is set" - yes, and it's set to `nil` :)

Comment: it just means that `@followed` is really `nil`. why? you shall intercept it. may be `@active_relationship.followed` is also `nil`

Comment: is just a typpo? Your action is called `showf` instead of `show`... If it is a typpo, then check that `params[:active_relationship]` contains something. If not, change the method name to `show`

Comment: @sss333 please add your `show_follow`  method

Comment: showf is show_follow sorry. the route   has: get     'showf'    =>      'users#show_follow'.

Comment: yes I know it's nil. But I can't work out why it's nil/how to not make it nil

Comment: params has active_relationship = 28 (which is the correct relationship

Comment: so i've got the relationship id set as active_relationship. I want to use that to find the followed_id of that relationship (a column in the relationship table)

Comment: @sss333 Once try changing this line `@followed = @active_relationship.follower` or this line `has_many :active_relationships,   class_name:  "Relationship",                                 foreign_key: "followed_id"`. either of them but not both

Comment: @choco I changed `@followed = @active_relationship.follower` but nothing changes in the error

Comment: @sss333 what about the other solution?

Comment: It's not the answer. The model is set up as I need it with the foreign key - don't want to change that.

Comment: There should be ways without doing that anyway right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65502/discussion-between-choco-and-sss333).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
def showf
    if params[:active_relationship]
      @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find_by(params[:active_relationship])
     @followed = User.find(@active_relationship.followed_id).name 
     @profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(@followed.id) will give u the object of profile table
    else 
      "No relationship found"
    end
end
```

This will give you expected output.

Comment: each variable worked in rails console, but did not translate across to the view when implemented in the controller.. not sure what to do..

Comment: worked it out! should have been def show_follow.. not def showf. While the route was redirecting correctly, I wasn't setting up the action correctly. :s